# When wiring batteries in both series and parallel to increase the V and Ah, is there a difference between series-parallel and parallel-series?

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, battery-charging, parallel, series

For example, to create a battery pack of 24 V and 24 Ah from four 12 V/12 Ah batteries what would be the difference in following two wrings.

**Figure A:** First create 2 series strips of 24 V/12 Ah and combine them in parallel to get 24 Ah/24 Ah.

```
          ___[-BATTERY+]_____[-BATTERY+]___
         |                                 |
TO LOAD -|                                 |+ TO LOAD
         |___[-BATTERY+]_____[-BATTERY+]___|
```

**Figure B:** First create 2 parallel strips of 12 V/24 Ah and combine them in series to get 24 V/24 Ah.

```
          ___[-BATTERY+]_____[-BATTERY+]___
         |                |                |
TO LOAD -|                |                |+ TO LOAD
         |___[-BATTERY+]__|__[-BATTERY+]___|
```

*Also which one of the above would be referred as series-parallel or parallel-series?

Answer (score 1):

Nomenclature. Your top example would be described as 2S2P first two cells in series and then this arranged as two parallel strings. The lower example would be 2P2S first two cells in parallel and then two of these in series.

The difference in performance is due to the 2P2S arrangement being able to self balance differences in the batteries performance for charge and discharge.

When charging if one cell is charging faster the voltage across that cell would have to rise this pushes more current into the other cell causing it to charge faster and hence balancing the charge.

The same effect in reverse applies to discharge.

Answer (score 0):

In term of performance,ideally it not difference.
But the difference come when we talking about BMS.
For fig. A you need 2 lower current BMS
For fig. B you need only one BMS with higher current rate.

Also if there are capacity difference, fig A will be cutt-off when battery cell with lowest capacity reach the cut-off voltage. But for fig B it will average the capacity of paralleled cell so it can last longer.